# Angularjs resource status description

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with angularjs app communicating with a REST API. The problem is the api returnes a status code and also adds a status description like HTTP/1.1 417 Invalid quantity. 
With jquery ajax the jqXHR object had a statusText property but with angularjs I can't seem to find how can I access this in my error handler. Needless to say I can't modify the API which for a 417 status code for example can return different status descriptions. 
I have found that I would need to change the angularjs library but in case of an update this would not be handy. I would have to change xhr.responseText to xhr.statusText. Can I somehow overwrite this function from my code and don't modify angular library?

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      completeRequest(
          callback, status || xhr.status, xhr.responseText, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the work around to get StatusText (as pointed out that some mobile browsers strip out DATA from successfull responses: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28470163/1586498

I have also discovered that .success and .error on $http in Angular does not pass the StatusText, you have to use .then(response)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an httpInterceptor as [outlined here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) during your module config.

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
  return function(promise) {
    return promise.then(function(response) {

      // do something on success

    }, function(response) {

      //do something for your 417 error
      if(response.status == 417) {
        alert("We've got a 417!");
        return $q.reject(response);
      }

      //some other error
      return $q.reject(response);
    });
  }
});


$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Comment: I already have an httpInterceptor. But in the error the response doesn't contain what I need. I have to change xhr.responseText to xhr.statusText. What I have found until now is that I need to modify httpBackend provider but I am stuck at that because I don't know how to use the decorator method

Answer (score 0):

The support for statusText was added in [AngularJS 1.2.16](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/CHANGELOG.md).