# $http.get() in controller not working for my API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am working on Application which uses **Angularjs**.I want to call api and get data using $http.get().My problem is when I use my api in url its not working whereas I use url which I found on w3schools tutorial is working fine.
here is my code :

```
 var url = "/api/v1/policycategory/get";
 $http.get(url).then(function (response) {        
    $scope.myString= response.statusText;
 });
```

Using my api I am getting my response in browser as below :

[{"id":1,"name":"Dependants only","displayName":"Dependants Only","dateTimeCreated":"2016-05-12T11:58:19.35"},{"id":2,"name":"One adult","displayName":"Single","dateTimeCreated":"2016-05-12T11:58:19.357"},{"id":3,"name":"One adult & dependant(s)","displayName":"Sole Parent","dateTimeCreated":"2016-05-12T11:58:19.363"},{"id":4,"name":"One adult & any dependants","displayName":"Sole Parent Plus","dateTimeCreated":"2016-05-12T11:58:19.367"},{"id":5,"name":"Two adults","displayName":"Couple","dateTimeCreated":"2016-05-12T11:58:19.367"},{"id":6,"name":"Two adults & dependant(s)","displayName":"Family","dateTimeCreated":"2016-05-12T11:58:19.37"},{"id":7,"name":"Two adults & any dependants","displayName":"Family Plus","dateTimeCreated":"2016-05-12T11:58:19.37"}]

**When I use my api,it does not run that part inside function**.

Comment: So it *does* work. You *do* get data back. That is a valid Json string. What is the problem?

Comment: why don't I get data back in my api ?

Comment: your api server is also serving your angular app or both are in different servers?

Comment: You just posted the data you get back from your api! Should you edit the question perhaps?

Comment: that is the data ,I got in browser

Comment: @DhruvGohil can you show what response object is containing when you hit your API.

Comment: this page suggests trying `response.data.statusText` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081032/angular-http-error-response-statustext-always-undefined

Comment: @AvantikaSaini I have updated my question.Please look at it once

Comment: @DhruvGohil could you clarify that your angular app is being served by the same API server or different one ?

Comment: yeah It's served by same API@Nivesh

Comment: well, then CORS is not the issue. But you can give is a shot and implement CORS in your API.

Comment: Your api returns the data that you can see in your browser. Do you really need the `statusText` ? If it is just for verification purpose then you can do it by checking `data.length` etc

Comment: When I use my api ,It does not run that part inside function then how can I do all that stuff.StatusText is not the issue.I have put it to check that, do I get anything or not@AvantikaSaini

Comment: inside your `then` function add `console.log(response.data)`. You can add other `console` statements to find out what `data` you are getting back.

Comment: I have already tried by setting up other properties inside it but that properties are not being updated ,that means code inside then function is not executed.@Venky

Comment: You haven't implemented the `errror call back` . That is the reason you are not seeing the error.  Follow this link and add `success call back` and `error call back`.  Add `console.log` statements in both and you will see what's happening.   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Also use `PostMan` or `Fiddler` to test your API before consuming in the front end. This way you can avoid these kind of problems in advance.

Comment: if response is null ,does it run then fuction ?@Venky

Comment: yes it will run. but it will fail when you try to access `response.something` so you should check for `null` condition before using `response` object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113032/discussion-between-dhruv-gohil-and-venky).

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `$scope.myString= response.statusText;` but your `response` does not have a field called `statusText`.

Comment: repsonse is the `ng` object. It will have statusText along with few other properties.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: When I use this  as url : http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php,Its working fine but when I use my url(My api),It does not run that part inside the $http

Answer (score 0):

yes you are getting the data but you are not accessing it correctly. If you write `$scope.myString = response[0].id;` the you will see that it has some value. You are trying to access `response.statusText` but the key `statusText` does not exist in your response

Comment: repsonse is the `ng` object. It will have `statusText` along with few other https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

you should return `data` not `statusText`

```
var url = "/api/v1/policycategory/get";
 $http.get(url).then(function (response) {        
    $scope.myString= response.data;
 });
```

Comment: How can he return `data` when no key named `data` exists. This is incorrect

Comment: @AvantikaSaini $http call return an response object contain 5 properties. [$http angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: once I tried using `response.data` but it gave the error `data is not defined`

Comment: @Avantika   `data` is not defined error you get when response is null or something else. But you will surely have 5 properties in `response` object.